# span content without an extra element tag

Tags: css, html, css-content

I am trying to creat plus and minus icons using spans for my accordians. I have managed to style up the span into a circle, however without putting a `<p>+</p>` inside the `<span class="accordian-icon"></span>` how can I put the '+' inside the span using the CSS content rule?

### HTML

```
<div class="accordian-head">
   <h3><a href="#">Normal text</a></h3><span class="accordian-icon"></span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.accordian-container .accordian-head span.accordian-icon{
  content:  "+";    
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin:10px;
 }
```

Comment: why can't you do it with a background image?

Comment: I can but I'm trying to use as less http requests as possible as this is a mobile site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLV62/) (as an example of how it may be done, there are a few approaches).

Importantly, the `content` property can only be used in conjunction with the `:after` or  `:before` pseudo elements.

CSS

```
.accordian-icon{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-radius:99px;
    background:blue;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.accordian-icon:after{
    color:white;
    content:'+';
    position:relative;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with using &:after/&:before and positioning them as absolutes on a relative container(the span in this example).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YoussefSH/yqt9M/) with a simple preview of what i mean.

HTML
`<span class="plus"></span>`

CSS

```
.plus {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
}

.plus:after {
    content: '+';
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```